# C# Determine process owner in unelevated application

Tags: c#, process, owner

I found some code that will tell me the owner of a process.  My problem is that it only works if the application has Administrator privileges.  Is there any way to do the same thing as an unelevated process?  Currently I get "Access Denied" error from the InvokeMethod call.

```
string query = "Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = \"" + sExeName + "\"";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
{
    string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
    int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
    if (returnVal == 0)
    {
        // return DOMAIN\user
        //string owner = argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
        //return owner;
        processUser = argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
        if (processUser == currentUser)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use Environment.UserName?

Comment: From what I understand that gives you the logged in user, not the credentials for the app.  So if someone chose "Run as different user", for example.